# How to exclude deploys inative in my github?

Tags: github

I don't want to show the old deploys in tab of  deploys in my project. How can I do this?

The github show all deploys inatives. 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to check with [GitHub support](https://github.com/contact), but there does not seem to be a way to change the *default* activity log content.

The [audit log](https://help.github.com/articles/reviewing-the-audit-log-for-your-organization/) (for an organization, [introduced in 2014](https://github.blog/2014-08-20-improved-audit-log/)) does have filtering mechanism. But evne that has a fixed default content.